# Name of a single branch of a collatz tree

Tags: terminology, collatz-conjecture

In the collatz conjecture, given a number N, you get the next number in the sequence by following one of two rules: if its even, you divide by two. If its odd, multiply by 3 and add 1.

You can follow this rule down to 1, and every number you choose for N seems to end its chain in 1, but we don't know why.

My question is, is there a name for any single chain of numbers all the way up to one?

I'm inclined to call it a "collatz branch", following the idea that all the collatz branches together form a collatz tree. But that's just a name I made up.

Comment: “Path” makes more sense to me than “branch.”

Comment: Given that all "paths" or "branches" unite in a common mainstream of the form $2^n$  on their way to $1$, they might be characterized as "tributaries." But like OP, that's just a name I made up.

Comment: Sounds like trajectory.

Comment: While "trajectory" is used more for general cases (means also continuous curves), specifically for discrete trajectories the term "orbit" is often used. - For the question of "branches": when you talk about "trees", then "branches" should make more sense than "pathes"... in any case: better stay in the same semantical field.